# Connection String doesn't work on the server, works everywhere else

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I have connection strings that look like:

`Data Source=mydomain.com;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True`

This works from our machines - except for when this code is run on the server. I get this message:
'Login Failed. The Login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows Authentication'

If I change the connection string data source to local:

`Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB;Integrated Security=True`

It works fine from the server - but obviously doesn't from our other computers.

I know this may be a good question for serverfault - but thought it better here, as it may be a simple software workaround that fixes it. We don't have a domain/active directory - just a few PC's all set with the same credentials as on the server.

I did check the firewall (turned it off on the server) with the same error.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You should be putting connection strings ect. in configuration files not hard coded into software.

Comment: does `mydomain.com` resolves correctly on the server ? Did you tried to add `mydomain.com` to the local intranet zone ? Did you tried to set `mydomain.com` as known loopback address ?

Comment: Is the web application configured to run under a user that has access to the server/database?

Comment: Steve: The domain does resolve correctly on the server. not sure how to set the local intranet zone, this is a winform app.  Setting the IP address fixed it.  Thanks! Ash-The connection string is in the 'settings' of the app. Lasse: yes - it is the same user (me) on both machines - and works fine when the connection string is local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the server IP insed of server name - Data Source=x.x.x.x;
also make sure the firewall is open to outside connections: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

Comment: Thanks - setting the IP address works. Is there a way to avoid doing this though?  We want to be able to update the domain in cases of outage etc - but won't be able to do that if we hardcode the IP address.

Comment: you can update your application/web server host file located on: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc you need to add line in the end of the file- x.x.x.x    yourdomain.com

Comment: Editing the hosts file did not correct this. If I hardcode the IP address, it works fine.  If I ping the domain it resolves properly to the IP address, which I suspect is why editing the hosts file isn't correcting it.   It resolves to the IP - but gives the 'untrusted domain, no windows authentication' error.  I did confirm that I edited the hosts file correctly (as administrator).  Any suggestions?

Comment: This occurs because the developer’s account has access to SQL Server, but the account IIS runs as does not have access - read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx

Comment: This is a winforms app that is not using IIS - so I don't think that is the problem.  Putting the IP address in the connection string is working for now, which is great. I patched SQL server (Service Pack), so I wonder if that has something to do with it...